# Question Involving Strength of Fodor's Lemma, CH Assumption

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The version of this question that does not assume CH is located here:

[Question Involving Strength of Fodor's Lemma, No CH Assumption](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425712/question-involving-strength-of-fodors-lemma-no-ch-assumption)

**Question:**

Based on the definitions below for function $t$ and the functions $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2\leq\alpha<\omega_1}$ and assuming CH, must there be a minimum element $\kappa \in \omega_1$ where $\kappa \in \phi_{\omega}(\kappa)$?

Note that there is some $\kappa \in \omega_1$ where $\kappa \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa)$ for each $\alpha < \omega$ due Fodor's lemma (Fodor would have each element of $\{ \kappa : \kappa \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa) \}$ map to a constant for each $\alpha$ in $\omega$ should $\phi_{\alpha}$ be *fully regressive* instead of just *almost regressive*.  See the comments below for clarification on the use of those terms here).

**Define $t(\alpha)$ and $t^{-1}(\alpha)$ for any ordinal $\alpha \geq 2$:**

Let $t(\alpha)$ equal a doublet of ordinals $(a,b)$ if $\alpha = 2$, a triplet of ordinals $(a,b,c)$ if $\alpha = 3$, a quadruplet of ordinals $(a,b,c,d)$ if $\alpha = 4$, and so on, for any ordinal $\alpha$.
Similarly, let $t^{-1}(x)$ equal $2$ for any doublet of ordinals $x$, $3$ for any triplet of ordinals $x$, $4$ for any quadruplet of ordinals $x$, and so on, as determined by the order type of $x$.

**Use of set builder notation:**

Consider the set of all doublets of ordinals such that each element of each doublet is a member of $\omega_1$.  It will become helpful to use set-builder notation in the following manner to define such a set:
$$\{t(2) : a,b \in t(2) \implies a,b \in \omega_1 \} = \{ (a,b) : a,b \in \omega_1 \} = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(a \in \omega_1,b \in \omega_1),\dots\}$$

**Define the functions $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2 \leq \alpha < \omega_1}$:**

Let each element of $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2 \leq \alpha < \omega_1}$ be *almost regressive* such that:

1) $$\phi_{\alpha} : \omega_1 \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \{ t(\alpha) : a,b,c,\dots \in t(\alpha) \implies a,b,c,\dots < \omega_1 \} \text{ is bijective},$$

2) $$a,b,c,\dots \leq \kappa \, \text{for each } a,b,c,\dots \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa), \, \text{and}$$

3) $$\zeta < \alpha \implies min\{ \phi_{\zeta}^{-1}(b) : \exists k \in b \text{ where } k \geq \phi_{\zeta}^{-1}(b)\} < min\{ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(b) : \exists k \in b \text{ where } k \geq \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(b)\}.$$

**Background as to question:**
I use the functions $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2\leq\alpha<\omega_1}$ to classify the ordinals less than $\omega_1$ in a paper I've written.  I am looking to confirm my understanding.  I am also curious if I need to (or should) refine my definition of function $t$ given that my notation may be less than ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost regressive"?

Comment: I do not understand condition 1 in your definition of the $\phi_\alpha$. Is the subindex $\alpha$ the same parameter that appears in the codomain? If that's the case, then the right hand side is either a singleton or empty. I assume you mean something else?

Comment: I also don't understand condition 2. You say that if $a\in\phi_\alpha(k)$ then $a\le\kappa$. Is this what the condition says? Because if that is what it says, it seems inconsistent with the fact that $\phi_\alpha(\kappa)$ is an $\alpha$-tuple. Maybe this will make more sense once you clarify condition 1...

Comment: "Almost regressive" uses $\leq$ for condition 2 whereas "(fully) regressive" would use $<$ for condition 2 and, further, condition 1 could not hold because, e.g., $\phi_{2}$ couldn't be bijective.  That is, regressive $\implies a,b,c,\dots < \kappa$ for each $a,b,c,\dots \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa)$ and no fully regressive function could be bijective under those terms given Fodor's constant.

Comment: If $t(2)$ equals a doublet $(a,b)$ of variables, then $\{t(2) : a,b,c, \dots \in t(2) \implies a,b,c,\dots < \omega_1 \} = \{(a,b) : \gamma,\beta \in (a,b) \implies \gamma,\beta \in \omega_1 \}$.  In English, it's the set of all doublets such that each doublet contains only variables from $\omega_1$.

Comment: Ok, this is better, but still makes no sense: usually an $\alpha$-tuple is understood to be a function from $\alpha$ to the universe, so its elements are literally ordered pairs, not ordinals. When you write that $\gamma\in t(\alpha)$ implies $\gamma\in\omega_1$, do you mean that the elements of the range of the $\alpha$-tuple under consideration are countable ordinals?

Comment: Assuming that my interpretation is correct, then consistently condition 1 fails as written for any $\alpha\ge\omega$, since there are too many $\alpha$-tuples. What I mean is: it looks like you are assuming the continuum hypothesis, but I doubt that is the case. Do you instead mean that $\phi_\alpha$ is a map that assigns to each nonzero countable ordinal an $\alpha$-tuple of countable ordinals, and that this assignment is injective? If you actually want a bijection, then you need to state your additional assumptions (such as CH) ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, assume CH for the sake of argument.

Comment: Ok. What is almost regressive?

Comment: We relax restriction #2 to $\leq$ for almost regressive instead of $<$ for regressive, which then allows condition 1 to hold.  E.g, trying to map $\omega_1 \setminus \{0\}$ onto $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(a \in \omega_1, b \in \omega_1),\dots\}$ bijectively is only possible if there is a stationary subset $S$ of $\omega_1$ where each element $\kappa$ of $S$ maps to a doublet containing $\kappa$.

Comment: Instead of assuming CH, is it enough to merely assume that $\omega_1$ has cofinality $\omega_1$?  I think the axiom of choice is enough then, as that would imply the cofinality is $\omega_1$?  Thank you too, btw.

Comment: No, it is not enough. Condition 1 implies CH.

Comment: I understand why CH must be assumed and upvoted your comment (sorry, I understand Cantor and that was a silly comment on my part while down a rabbit hole).  What if I use only the $t(\omega)$ that are computable though?

Comment: I have a way of defining which $t(\alpha)$ are computable for $\alpha \geq \omega$ and should fix my notation too, so perhaps we should just assume CH for this question or abandon it.  Thank you again.

Comment: @AplanisTophet: A little comment on writing style; it is easier to understand the question if you write it to be chronologically coherent. I would *start* with the background to the question, *then* do the definition of terms (in the question, not in the comments), and *finish* with the actual question.

Comment: Thank you Vsotvep.  I had to fix something just now on the Non CH version.  I confess that I am struggling with learning to proofread my own work and get some of the errors out at this point.  I believe that I have things in order and will continue to think about it.  At the same time, nobody else pointed out what I felt was a fairly obvious error, so hoping somebody at least attempts to make sense of my other question too.