# Question Involving Strength of Fodor's Lemma, No CH Assumption

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

This version of the question is meant to avoid assuming the continuum hypothesis (as is done in the link below) and clarify the notation.

[Question Involving Strength of Fodor's Lemma, CH Assumption](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420874/question-involving-strength-of-fodors-lemma)

**Question:**

Must there be a minimum element $\kappa \in \omega_1$ where $\kappa \in \phi_{\omega}(\kappa)$ given the definitions below?

Note that there is some $\kappa \in \omega_1$ where $\kappa \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa)$ for each $\alpha < \omega$ due Fodor's lemma (Fodor would have each element of $\{ \kappa : \kappa \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa) \}$ map to a constant for each $\alpha$ in $\omega$ should $\phi_{\alpha}$ be *fully regressive* instead of just *almost regressive*.  The comments in the above link address the meaning of *almost regressive* and *fully regressive*).

**Optional Second Question:**

Is $C$ both countable and non-empty on each iteration ($C$ is defined as a local variable within the definition of sequence $T$, step 2, sub-step d)?

**Where $a,b$ are ordinals:**

1) $a=b$ does not imply $(a,b) = (a) = (b)$.
2) $a \neq b$ does not imply $(a,b) = (b,a)$.

**Define $t(\alpha)$ and $t^{-1}(\alpha)$ for any ordinal $\alpha \geq 2$:**

Let $t(\alpha)$ equal a doublet of ordinals $(a,b)$ if $\alpha = 2$, a triplet of ordinals $(a,b,c)$ if $\alpha = 3$, a quadruplet of ordinals $(a,b,c,d)$ if $\alpha = 4$, and so on, for any ordinal $\alpha$.
Similarly, let $t^{-1}(x)$ equal $2$ for any doublet of ordinals $x$, $3$ for any triplet of ordinals $x$, $4$ for any quadruplet of ordinals $x$, and so on, as determined by the order type of $x$.

**Use of set builder notation:**

Consider the set of all doublets of ordinals such that each element of each doublet is a member of $\omega_1$.  It will become helpful to use set-builder notation in the following manner to define such a set:
$$\{t(2) : a,b \in t(2) \implies a,b \in \omega_1 \} = \{ (a,b) : a,b \in \omega_1 \} = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(a \in \omega_1,b \in \omega_1),\dots\}$$

**Define the set $P$:**

$$P = \{ t(\omega) : a,b,c,\dots \in t(\omega) \implies a,b,c,\dots \, \text{is a computable sequence} \, \text{and } a,b,c, \dots \in \{0,1\} \} \equiv \, \text{the set of computable binary sequences}$$

**Define the functions $(r_{\alpha})_{\omega \leq \alpha < \omega_1}$:**

Let $r_{\alpha} :  \alpha \rightarrow \omega$ be bijective.

**Define 'Likewise Computable':**

Let $t(\alpha) = ((\beta + a)_0, (\beta + b)_1, (\beta + c)_2, \dots)$ be likewise computable for any ordinal $\alpha$ if and only if $\omega \leq \alpha < \omega_1$, $\beta \in \omega_1$, and an $\omega$-type ordering by index $( (\gamma)_{r_{\alpha}^{-1}(0)}, (\zeta)_{r_{\alpha}^{-1}(1)}, (\mu)_{r_{\alpha}^{-1}(2)},\dots )$ of the $\alpha$-type ordering $( a_{r_{\alpha}(0)}, b_{r_{\alpha}(1)}, c_{r_{\alpha}(2)},\dots )$ is an element of $P$.

**Define the functions $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2 \leq \alpha < \omega_1}$:**

Let each element of $(\phi_{\alpha})_{2 \leq \alpha < \omega_1}$ be *almost regressive* such that:

1) $$\alpha < \omega \implies \phi_{\alpha} : \omega_1 \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \{ t(\alpha) : a,b,c,\dots \in t(\alpha) \implies a,b,c,\dots \in \omega_1 \} \text{ is bijective},$$

2) $$\alpha \geq \omega \implies \phi_{\alpha} : \omega_1 \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \{ t(\alpha) : a,b,c,\dots \in t(\alpha) \implies a,b,c,\dots \in \omega_1 \, \text{and } t(\alpha) \, \text{is likewise computable}\} \text{ is bijective},$$

3) $a,b,c,\dots \leq \kappa$ for each $a,b,c,\dots \in \phi_{\alpha}(\kappa)$, and

4) $\zeta < \alpha \implies \min\{ \phi_{\zeta}^{-1}(b) : \exists k \in b \text{ where } k \geq \phi_{\zeta}^{-1}(b)\} < \min\{ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(b) : \exists k \in b \text{ where } k \geq \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}(b)\}$.

**Define function $f$:**

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\phi_{t^{-1}(x)}^{-1}(x) & \text{if, given } x \, \text{has order type } \alpha, 2 \leq \alpha < \omega \, \text{or } x \, \text{is likewise computable} \\
\text{empty string} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

**Define $k(\alpha)$ for any ordinal $\alpha \in \omega_1$:**

$$k(\alpha) = \{ x : f(x) = \alpha \}$$

**Define function $h$:**

$$h(\alpha) = \begin{cases}
min\{ t^{-1}(x) : x \in k(\alpha) \text{ and } \forall y \in x(y < \alpha) \} & \text{if } \alpha \in \omega_1 \\
1 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

**Define function $g$:**

For any set of ordinals, $A$, let $g(A)$ be the set of all ordered doublets, triplets, quadruplets, and so on, that can be comprised from the elements of $\omega_1 \cap A$:
$$g(A) = \{ t(\alpha) : t(\alpha) \setminus (A \cap \omega_1) = \emptyset \text{ and } 2 \leq \alpha < \omega_1 \}$$

**Define the sequence $T$:**

Define a (potentially transfinite) sequence $T = t_1, t_2, t_3, \dots$ over $\omega_1$ iterations where:

**Step 1)** Let $t_1 = 0, t_2 = 1, t_3 = 2$, and iteration counter $m = 1$.

**Step 2)** Each $t_n$, where $n \geq 4$, is defined by the previous elements of the sequence.  Starting with $n = 4$:

a)  If $m$ is a countable limit ordinal and $T$ is of order type $\omega$, free up space in $T$ by first letting $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be defined for odd indexes and undefined for even indexes:  $s_{n \cdot 2 - 1} = t_{n}$.  Then, set $t_1 = s_1, t_2 = s_2, t_3 = s_3, \dots$.  Finally, if $m = \omega$, set $t_j$ undefined for any index $j > i$ where $t_j = t_i$ and $i,j < \omega$.

b)  Let $A = \{ t_i \in T : i < n \}$.  E.g., $A = \{0, 1, 2 \}$ on the first iteration.

c)  Let $B = \{ f(x) : x \in (g(A) \setminus \{ y \in g(A) : t^{-1}(y) \neq h(f(y))\} ) \}$.  Using the previous elements of the sequence $A$, this step creates a set $B$ of all the new ordinals implied by letting function $f$ range over $g(A)$.  The restriction of $g(A)$ to $A \cap \omega_1$ ensures that $B$ remains countable for this particular $T$ sequence.

d)  Let $C = B \setminus A$ and let $c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots$ be an enumeration of $C$ that is also well ordered if $|C| \neq \aleph_0$.  This step removes any redundant elements from $B$ before potentially well ordering them so that we can add them to $T$.

e)  If $|C| < \aleph_0$ or if a transfinite $T$ is desired, set $t_n = c_1, t_{n+1} = c_2, t_{n+2} = c_3, \dots$ and then proceed to step 3.  If a transfinite $T$ is not desired, proceed to sub-step f.

f)  Let $T’ = t’_1, t’_2, t’_3, \dots$ be a subsequence of the remaining undefined elements of $T$ and set $t’_1 = c_1, t’_3 = c_2, t’_5 = c_3, \dots$.

**Step 3)** Let $j$ be the first ordinal such that $t_j$ is undefined.  If $j>n$, set $n = j$.  Increase the iteration counter by letting $m = m + 1$, and then repeat step 2.

Comment: There is a correctable issue in that $\phi_{\omega}$ and higher can't be bijective the way these are defined.  This question was posted in too hasty a fashion.  I apologize and will fix here shortly.

Comment: I believe it is still confusing. Your $\omega$-type ordering is written down as if it is an $\alpha$-type ordering. I guess you mean that you reorder the terms of the $\alpha$-type according to $r_\alpha$ such that the resulting sequence has order type $\omega$?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Once the $\alpha$ type ordering is reordered into an $\omega$ type ordering and the constant $\beta$ is dropped, the sequence can be evaluated as either being in or not in $P$.

Comment: It helps to see sequences as functions; a sequence $x$ with order-type $\alpha<\omega_1$ is a function $x:\alpha\to\omega_1$. Then we can get a sequence with order type $\omega$ by taking some bijective $r_\alpha:\omega\to\alpha$ and considering the function $x\circ r_\alpha:\omega\to\omega_1$

Comment: I very much appreciate you looking over things some Vsotvep.  I see a minor clerical change that I can make to the definition of $B$ by using $y$ instead of $x$.  It currently reads $B = \{ f(x) : x \in (g(A) \setminus \{ x \in g(A) : t^{-1}(x) \neq h(f(x))\} ) \}$.  I am changing it to $B = \{ f(x) : x \in (g(A) \setminus \{ y \in g(A) : t^{-1}(y) \neq h(f(y))\} ) \}$.  If you (anyone) sees anything else that could be clarified further, please let me know and thank you.  Otherwise, I do not intend to inconvenience by editing further so please don't hesitate to attempt the question(s)!

Comment: I have an answer as to the first question.  Yes, there must exist a $\kappa \in \omega_1$ such that $\kappa \in \phi_{\omega}(\kappa)$.  More specifically, there is a stationary subset $S_0$ of $\omega_1 \setminus \{0\}$ where $\gamma \in S_0$ implies $\gamma \in \phi_{\omega}(\gamma)$.  If I had made $\phi_{\omega}$ regressive instead of just almost regressive, then every element of $S_0$ would instead map to a constant and $\phi_{\omega}$ couldn't be bijective as a result (similar to Fodor's lemma).  As to the second question, did anyone care enough to get that far?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm trying to answer my own question here, please feel free to up (down) vote or provide a better answer.  I will leave the question open.

**Proof Statement:**  There must exist an element $\kappa \in \omega_1$ such that $\kappa \in \phi_{\omega}(\kappa)$.

Incorporate the definitions from above.

**Define the function $\psi(\gamma)$ for $\gamma \in \omega_1 \setminus \{0\}$:**

$$\psi(\gamma) = \{ t(\omega) : a,b,c,\dots \in t(\omega) \implies 0 \leq a,b,c,\dots < \gamma \, \text{and } t(\omega) \, \text{is likewise computable}\}$$

**Define the ordinal $\upsilon(\gamma)$ for $\gamma \in \omega_1 \setminus \{0\}$:**

$$\upsilon(\gamma) = \{ x \in \omega_1 : x < sup\{ \phi_{\omega}^{-1}(y) : y \in \psi(\gamma) \} \}$$

We have $\gamma < \beta \implies \upsilon(\gamma) \leq \upsilon(\beta)$.  Also, we have that $\{ \upsilon(\gamma) : \gamma \in \omega_1 \}$ must be unbounded in $\omega_1$.  We can consider the set $L$:

$$L = \{ x \in \omega_1 \setminus \{0\} : \forall y \in x (\upsilon(y) < \upsilon(x)) \}$$

Where $|L| = |\omega_1|$ (because $sup\{ \phi_{\omega}^{-1}(y) : y \in \psi(\gamma) \} \in \omega_1$ implies $\upsilon(\gamma) \in \omega_1$ for any $\gamma \in \omega_1$, assuming $\omega_1$ has cofinality $\omega_1$), we can start to wrap up the proof.

**Define the function $\varrho$:**

$$\varrho(\alpha_i) = \gamma_i, \, \text{given the well orderings } \alpha_i \in (\omega_1, <) \, \text{and }\gamma_i \in (L,<)$$

**Define the normal function $\xi$ for $\alpha \in \omega_1$:**

$$\xi(\alpha) = \upsilon(\varrho(\alpha))$$

There must be a first fixed point according to the fixed point lemma for normal functions.  The fixed points of function $\xi$ are exactly the elements of $\{ x \in \omega_1 : x \in \phi_{\omega}(x) \}$.  Therefore, let $\kappa = min\{ x \in\omega_1 : \xi(x) = x \} = min\{ x \in \omega_1 : x \in \phi_{\omega}(x) \}$.  $\square$